# Showing largest divisible number instead of all numbers

Tags: java

I've started to learn basics of Java and currently I have to find and print largest divisible number.

For example number 30 can be divided by 2, 3, 6 and 10 so on the console I should show only 10. Another example is number 12 which can be divided by 2, 3 and 6 - should show 6.

I'm stuck at the point where I show the largest number. What I have so far is this one

```
    double isItDivisible = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
   
    int num = 2;
    if ( isItDivisible % 2 == 0 ) {
        System.out.println("The number is divisible by " + num);
    } else if ( isItDivisible % 3 == 0 ) {
        num = 3;
        System.out.println("The number is divisible by " + num);
    } else if ( isItDivisible % 6 == 0 ) {
        num = 6;
        System.out.println("The number is divisible by " + num);
    } else if ( isItDivisible % 10 == 0 ) {
        num = 10;
        System.out.println("The number is divisible by " + num);
    } else if ( isItDivisible % 7 == 0 ) {
        System.out.println("The number is divisible by " + 7); 
    }
```

The snipped display the first occurrence instead of the largest.
You can tell how new I'm based on the snipped so please bear with me.

Comment: Do you need to only check 2, 3, 6, 10 and 7? Or basically any number except the input itself? Aside from that, there are already a few problems/questions qwith your code: 1) do you _really_ want to handle double values? This could make the process harder if you don't want to check for specific values only. Maybe you want to use `Integer.parseInt()` instead. 2) don't check for the lowest divisible first but start with the highest and work your way down (since you want the highest)

Comment: Yes, I need to divide only by 2, 3, 6, 10 and 7. Well I didn't think of reverse and start from highest. Let me try

Comment: I still trying to figure what is better to be used in given situation `int` or `double`. I've reversed the checks and now is working correctly. Why I didn't tough of this way... Thank you!

Comment: Put the largest division as the first if, the second largest in the second (else) if, etc. Alternatively: only use `if`s, in the opposite direction but only print something after all of them are done an `num` contains the largest divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to find the highest divisible number that is not the input you could do the following:

```
int highest = 1; //1 should always apply - at least for integers

//iterate from highest to lowest number
for( int d = input-1; d > 1; d-- ) {
  //stop at the first number that divides the input without a rest
  if( input % d == 0 ) {
    highest = d;
    break;
  }
}
```

If you want to check specific numbers only, you could modify that to use a sorted collection of numbers.

```
//TreeSet is sorted and the reserved comparator makes it sort from high to low
SortedSet<Integer> divisors = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reversed());

//if the collection itself is sorted the order of additions doesn't matter
//if you're using a list and don't sort it after adding elements then order of insertion is relevant though
divisors.add(2);
divisors.add(10);
divisors.add(3);
divisors.add(7);
divisors.add(6);

Integer highest = null;

//iterates in sorted order
for( Integer d : divisors ) {
  if( input % d == 0 ) {
    highest = d;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand. The solution with for is understandable perfectly and it is way better that multiple if/esle's. The second solution is a bit non clear since I didn't saw this TreeSet before and now is good time to check it. Thanks

Comment: @Ivanov instead of `TreeSet` you could use `List<Integer> divisors = Arrays.asList(10,7,6,3,2);`. If the order is not kept at insertion as it is in this example you'd then need to call `Collections.sort(divisors, Comparator.reversed())`. Using a set and `TreeSet` specifically has the following advantages: 1) you can't add duplicates, 2) you can't forget to sort the set because it will keep itself sorted all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    public static void  main(String[] args)
    { 
        // Scanner Class 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double isItDivisible = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        
        int high = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < isItDivisible; i++) {
            if (isItDivisible % i == 0) {
                high = i;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(high);
    }
```

***Edit :*** With divide by pecific numbers **2,3,6,7,10**:

```
public static void  main(String[] args)
    { 
        // Scanner Class 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double isItDivisible = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        
        int high = 0;       
        
        int[] divide = {2,3,6,7,10};
        Arrays.sort(divide);
        
        for (int i : divide) {
            if (isItDivisible % i == 0) {
                high = i;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(high);
    }
```

Comment: Thank but doesn't work as I expect. For example if my input is 30 should show me 10 (since I divide by 2,3,6,7 and 10) but is showing 15.